# Circular dependencies issue with wic and fitImage+Initramfs

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build sd card image by using wic in Yocto. And found that it triggers error if I enable fitImage with bundle initramfs. If I disable INITRAMFS_IMAGE it works OK. How to fix this circular dependencies issue ?

```
ERROR: 1099 unbuildable tasks were found.#####################################################################                                                                                                                | ETA:  0:00:05
These are usually caused by circular dependencies and any circular dependency chains found will be printed below. Increase the debug level to see a list of unbuildable tasks.
Identifying dependency loops (this may take a short while)...

ERROR: 
Dependency loop #1 found:
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/../meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_assemble_fitimage_initramfs (dependent Tasks ['device-tree.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_complete', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_bundle_initramfs'])
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/../meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_deploy (dependent Tasks ['linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_assemble_fitimage_initramfs', 'depmodwrapper-cross_1.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_packagedata', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_bundle_initramfs'])
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_wic (dependent Tasks ['fsbl_git.bb:do_deploy', 'mtools_4.0.18.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'bitstream-extraction_git.bb:do_deploy', 'gptfdisk_1.0.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'device-tree.bb:do_deploy', 'u-boot-zynq-uenv.bb:do_deploy', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_rootfs_wicenv', 'u-boot-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_deploy', 'external-hdf.bb:do_deploy', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_deploy', 'dosfstools_4.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'parted_3.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'xilinx-bootbin_1.0.bb:do_deploy'])
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_complete (dependent Tasks ['u-boot-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_cpio', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_wic', 'u-boot-zynq-uenv.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'xilinx-bootbin_1.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image'])

Dependency loop #2 found:
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/../meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_assemble_fitimage_initramfs (dependent Tasks ['device-tree.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_complete', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_bundle_initramfs'])
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/../meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_deploy (dependent Tasks ['linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_assemble_fitimage_initramfs', 'depmodwrapper-cross_1.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_packagedata', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_bundle_initramfs'])
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_wic (dependent Tasks ['fsbl_git.bb:do_deploy', 'mtools_4.0.18.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'bitstream-extraction_git.bb:do_deploy', 'gptfdisk_1.0.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'device-tree.bb:do_deploy', 'u-boot-zynq-uenv.bb:do_deploy', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_rootfs_wicenv', 'u-boot-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_deploy', 'external-hdf.bb:do_deploy', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_deploy', 'dosfstools_4.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'parted_3.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'xilinx-bootbin_1.0.bb:do_deploy'])
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_complete (dependent Tasks ['u-boot-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_cpio', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_wic', 'u-boot-zynq-uenv.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'xilinx-bootbin_1.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image'])
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/../meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_bundle_initramfs (dependent Tasks ['linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_install', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_complete'])

Dependency loop #3 found:
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/../meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_bundle_initramfs (dependent Tasks ['linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_install', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_complete'])
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/../meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_deploy (dependent Tasks ['linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_assemble_fitimage_initramfs', 'depmodwrapper-cross_1.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_packagedata', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_bundle_initramfs'])
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_wic (dependent Tasks ['fsbl_git.bb:do_deploy', 'mtools_4.0.18.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'bitstream-extraction_git.bb:do_deploy', 'gptfdisk_1.0.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'device-tree.bb:do_deploy', 'u-boot-zynq-uenv.bb:do_deploy', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_rootfs_wicenv', 'u-boot-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_deploy', 'external-hdf.bb:do_deploy', 'linux-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_deploy', 'dosfstools_4.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'parted_3.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'xilinx-bootbin_1.0.bb:do_deploy'])
  Task /build/zynq/yocto/tiny/sources/core/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_complete (dependent Tasks ['u-boot-xlnx_2018.3.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_cpio', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image_wic', 'u-boot-zynq-uenv.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'xilinx-bootbin_1.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'core-image-minimal.bb:do_image'])
```

Comment: I used a custom image type bbclass to handle that kind of configuration, I didn't use kernel-fitimage for this.

Comment: this is one of approach, but I prefer to use as much possible standard yocto features.

Answer (score 1):

In your initramfs image recipe (the one specified in `INITRAMFS_IMAGE`), remove `wic` as an `IMAGE_FSTYPE`. This should remove it only for the initramfs image, and allow your main image still to build wic images.

```
IMAGE_FSTYPES_remove = " wic wic.gz"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had something similar going on for a yocto build of xilinx.  I had to exclude wic.qemu-sd to remove the circular dependencies.